# Aren't Sansa and Tyrion still married?

Tags: game-of-thrones

Watching *Game of Thrones* Season 8 Episode 3, Sansa makes a reference that she and Tyrion were married, but this is a genuine question as I am unsure if I missed something.

Did a septon or someone annul their marriage or has Sansa switched to worshiping the old gods somewhere along the way?

I know she married Ramsay but I don't even know if that was an actual binding marriage or just coercive marriage.

Comment: https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/134678/is-sansa-and-tyrions-marriage-still-legitimate + https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/161207/how-can-sansa-stark-be-forced-to-marry + https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/95350/isnt-sansa-already-married

Answer (score 21, accepted):

This has been asked and answered over at https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/95350/isnt-sansa-already-married

In season 5, episode 3:

> BAELISH: (They begin walking). I assure you she's still a virgin. Tyrion never consummated the marriage. **By the law of the land, she's no man's wife.** Inspect her, if you must.
>
> ROOSE: I leave that to the brothel keeper. It's her name I need, not her virtue.
>
> BAELISH: Then I have delivered everything I've promised.
>
> ROOSE: And you prepared for the consequences. When the Lannisters hear I've wed Sansa Stark to Ramsay...
>
> BAELISH: The Lannister name doesn't mean what it once did. Tywin is dead. He kept his house in power through sheer will. Without him, Jaime has one hand and no allies, Tommen is a soft boy, not a king to fear.
>
> ROOSE: The Queen will be enraged.
>
> BAELISH: Queen Margaery adores Sansa. Cersei is Queen Mother, a title whose importance wanes with each passing day.

Comment: I'm going to accept this on the basis of them being as good as annulled due to nobody who would be willing to say otherwise . Annulment does exist in the show.

Answer (score 9):

## Unclear.

It seems that even historians are debating this.

> That said, Huffington Post asked some experts what they thought and
>   got some conflicting answers. Nancy F. Cott, Jonathan Trumbull
>   Research Professor of American History at Harvard University, told the
>   outlet that Sansa and Tyrion were no longer married due to a lack of
>   consummation. However, Ruth Mazo Karras, Lecky Professor of History at
>   Trinity College Dublin, had a conflicting answer.
>
> "Consummation was not necessary for a marriage," Karras said. "As long
>   as both parties are of age, not too closely related to each other and
>   all other things that would make it a valid marriage, once they have
>   said their vows, they are married and they stay married. Even if they
>   separated, they wouldn't be able to marry anybody else."
>
> ---
>
> <sub>[Are Sansa & Tyrion Still Married? - Bustle](https://www.bustle.com/p/are-sansa-tyrion-still-married-their-got-season-8-reunion-showed-how-things-have-changed-between-them-17036650)</sub>

Littlefinger seems to assume that the marriage is no longer valid/never was.

> Furthermore, the professor went on to say that she believed Ramsay and Sansa's marriage was invalid and adulterous and that she and the Bolton son were never fully married. That said, it seems like Littlefinger had a different interpretation, since he handed Sansa over to the Boltons back in Season 5 with the assurance that the Stark was still a virgin.
>
> ---
>
> <sub>[Are Sansa & Tyrion Still Married? - Bustle](https://www.bustle.com/p/are-sansa-tyrion-still-married-their-got-season-8-reunion-showed-how-things-have-changed-between-them-17036650)</sub>

So, as far as we know, there is no easy answer.

Comment: As far as I can tell, the only authorities that would decide would be the crown and the faith. The faith is not exactly operating in Kings Landing at this point and if there were any records in the Sept of Balor of the marriage they are destroyed now. The crown I guess would see Tyrion as still sentenced to die so perhaps effectively Sansa is at most effectively a widow in the crown’s eyes. Or the crown just doesn’t care. I suspect Danerys and/or Jon would happily grant an annulment. Or maybe their marriage will end up playing a part in any negotiations to come.

Comment: Why are they asking Professors of history for this answer and calling them experts on the world GRRM has created? In George's world, Consummation is required to make the wedding binding, if not consummated, it can be set aside by High Septon or a council of Faith on request of either party. A divorce doesn't exist. Tyrion never consummated the wedding but Sansa never requested an annulment. So Sansa' marriage to Ramsay in the show was illegal and not binding as she was already Tyrion's wife. TLDR, Sansa and Tyrion are still very much married if George's rules still apply in D&D's world